# Calculate difference between DropDownList Value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStart1" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                <asp:ListItem>9:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEnd1" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                <asp:ListItem>9:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStart2" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                <asp:ListItem>9:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEnd2" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                <asp:ListItem>9:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxRow1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStart3" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                <asp:ListItem>9:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEnd3" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                <asp:ListItem>9:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStart4" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                <asp:ListItem>9:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEnd4" runat="server" CssClass="ddl">
                <asp:ListItem>9:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10:00</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11:00</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxRow2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxCol1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxCol2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

<div id="content"></div>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ddl").each(function (index) {
            $(this).change(function () {
                calculateSumRow();
                calculateSumCol();
            });
        });
    });

    function calculateSumRow() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".ddl").each(function (index) {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });

        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#txtBoxRow1").value(sum.toFixed(2));
    }

    function calculateSumRow() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".ddl").each(function (index) {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });

        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#txtBoxCol1").value(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
</script>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to calculate the number of hour on each row and column.
Would like the code to be the most dynamic as possible using index to call my Ids. I'm pretty new to JQuery.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to calculate. Could you explain more, perhaps with an example

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can add `start` and `end` classes to your ddls, like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStart1" runat="server" CssClass="ddl start">
```

and

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEnd1" runat="server" CssClass="ddl end">
```

This code would solve:

```
function differenceInMinutes($startDdl, $endDdl){
  var startParts = $startDdl.val().split(":");
      endParts = $endDdl.val().split(":"),
      startInMinutes = parseInt(startParts[1]) + parseInt(startParts[0]) * 60,
      endInMinutes = parseInt(endParts[1]) + parseInt(endParts[0]) * 60;
  return endInMinutes - startInMinutes;
}
```

I don't know in which event you want to get that difference. The following code alerts the difference when one changes

```
$(".ddl").change(function(){
   var $startDdl = $(this).closest("td").find(".ddl.start"),
       $endDdl = $(this).closest("td").find(".ddl.end"),
       diff = differenceInMinutes($startDdl, $endDdl);
   alert("Diff in minutes: " + diff)          
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers